# Limit of an Indicator function

Tags: measure-theory

According to an instructor, the following is true:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{1_{\mathrm{[n,n+1]}}} = \mathbf{1_{[\varnothing]}} =0,$$ where  $\mathbf{1}$ is the [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) and the limit is taken from the interval $[n,n+1]$. My problem in understanding this result, is that the limit of the interval length (the distance between $n$ and $n+1$), considering $\mathbb{R}$, would be $$\lim_{n \to \infty}|n-n+1|= \lim_{n \to \infty}1 = 1,$$ which does not match with the first result. I am searching for an explanation why the first result is true, and why my intuition goes vastly wrong here.

Comment: Which notion of convergence for functions are you considering?

Comment: @Rasmus: I am thinking about the standard epsilon-delta criterion ($\forall\epsilon > 0\exists\delta>0 $,so that $\forall x>\delta: |f(x)-b| < \epsilon$ with $b$ as the limit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointwise limit of your indicator functions is the zero-function since given any $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ there is some $N$ with $|\alpha|\notin [n,n+1]$ for all $N \geq n$.